# R: Stacking mismatched data.frames

Tags: r, dataframe

I would like to stack vertically two data frames that do not match in variables. For the variables that do not appear in one of the data frames, I would like the variables to be filled in with whatever missing values are appropriate `NA` or `""` as the case may be. I would program something myself but I hate to reinvent the wheel if someone already has programmed this tool.

```
A <- data.frame(a=1:10, b=rnorm(10), c=rnorm(10))
B <- data.frame(a=1:10, c=rnorm(10), d=rnorm(10))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `rbindlist` after keeping the data.frames in a list

```
library(data.table)#v1.9.5+
rbindlist(list(A,B), fill=TRUE)
```

Or

```
library(dplyr)
bind_rows(A,B)
```

Or

```
library(plyr)
rbind.fill(A, B)
```

Comment: I'll add the `plyr` one here to keep it all in one referable answer.